# Jetty Http/2 Client on Android

Tags: android, jetty

I'm trying to use Jetty HTTP/2 client on Android to talk to a custom HTTP/2 service. I can't see a way to start the android HTTP/2 app using ALPN as boot parameter. Is there a way can I disable ALPN for Jetty client or some workaround to activate ALPN during the boot time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As answered](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg06474.html) in the [[jetty-users] mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/).

Not possible.

HTTP/2 pretty much requires TLS/ALPN.

The way to do that, currently, is to modify the Java SSL classes at bootclasspath time.

The Jetty Project has written this modification into the `alpn-boot.jar` for the standard OpenJDK based Java envs.

There's no way for a normal Android application to do xbootclasspath on a normal android device.

Options you have.

- Convince Google to include alpn-boot in the base Android image (AOSP).
- Convince Google to include xbootclasspath support for Android Apps.
- Build your own Android image with alpn-boot built-in.
- Built a native ALPN and/or HTTP/2 processor and use it via JNI with your Android application.

Good Luck,